# Which event I can use after the chart is completely drawn and animation is finished in ext.js 6.x?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I want to download the chart in the background mode, but I don't know when chart is completely drawn and all animation is finished. For example:

```
var chart = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'polar',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    store: {
       fields: ['Name', 'Data'],
       data: [
          { 'Name': 'Price',     'Data': 100 },
          { 'Name': 'Revenue %', 'Data': 100 },
          { 'Name': 'Growth %',  'Data': 100 },
          { 'Name': 'Product %', 'Data': 100 },
          { 'Name': 'Market %',  'Data': 100 }
       ]
    },
    axes: [{
        type: 'category',
        position: 'angular',
        grid: true
    }, {
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'radial',
        grid: true
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'radar',
        xField: 'Name',
        yField: 'Data',
   }],
   listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
             chart.download(); // not work
        }
   }
});

Ext.create({
   xtype: 'panel',
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   dockedItems: [{
       xtype: 'toolbar',
       dock: 'top',
       items: [{
           xtype: 'button',
           text: 'download chart',
           handler: function() {
               chart.download(); // works correctly
           }
       }]
   }]
});

var renderCt = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(renderCt);
chart.render(renderCt);
```

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1l6l)

When I click to button "download chart". Chart is downloaded correctly, but when the event "afterrender" is fired I get the error or the downloaded file is empty (more precisely image is transparent). It is happened because chart is not drawn fully.

I describe my case. I have a some charts on the page and they have some setting for display on this page. But it is settings not full. I want to send data of charts (image base64 data) on my server. It is data should be full (for example set the size of images more then displayed on the page (300x300 - on page -> 600x600 - send to server) and add some other information which not fit in the page (legend and other)).

I.e I want to send on my server more then one chart with full settings with a single request, with will be contain all full data of charts (base64 data). I should know when all charts to completely drawn in the background mode and I can send data to the server.

Is there any event which fired when the chart is completely drawn and animation is finished?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.chart.PolarChart.html#method-afterShow

But you should rethink the design, a download without explicit user interaction is bad...
Also check out [this chromium commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/aaad992eef8e8c1e879f72afd9dabb05d3855e67)

Comment: `afterShow` only refers to the component itself, it doesn't have any impact on the chart animations.

Comment: I know what download charts in the background mode not exactly right. I described my case into the question above. I don't know what design I should use for this case.